# Nested form with has_many through with existing records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In my application I have Customers and I have Contacts. Customers can many contacts and Contacts can have many Customers. They are associated through a CustomerContact table. The thing is that the database can only have one unique Contact based on their email address.

What that, I want to create a form where the user can enter in the Customer information and as many Contacts as they want. I accomplish this using the [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon). Now the thing is that there isn't a "select an existing contact" there are just text fields and the idea is that when the form is submitted the system could see if a contact already exists in the system via an existing email address and not only assign the customer to the contact, but also update the existing contact information. If it is a new contact, it would just insert a new contact into the database and assign the contact to the customer.

Now obviously this is completely outside the normal way of doing things. You would normally have some sort of lookup and then select an existing contact, but that not what the boss wants.

### Here is the issue I'm having

Rails was always throwing an error "Contacts email has already been taken" when I was entering the email address for a contact that existed in the database. "No problem I thought", for existing contacts, I'll look in the database and create an id attribute on the contact by manipulating the params in the controller. So I wrote the code below:

```
# convert the params to a Hash so we can manuipulate them
myparams = customer_params.to_h

# if we have contacts we want to assign to the customer
if myparams['contacts_attributes']
  # loop through each contact they entered
  myparams['contacts_attributes'].each do |k,v|
    # see if the contact exists in the database and isn't being destroyed
    if Contact.exists?(email: v['email']) && v['_destroy'] != '1'
      # grab the contact information
      contact = Contact.where(email: v['email']).first
      # just a double check that we got the contact from the database
      if contact
        # create an id attribute for the contact
        myparams['contacts_attributes'][k]['id'] = contact.id
      end
    end
  end
end
```

"Beautiful!!!" or so I thought. When I tried to save the contact I was met with the following error:

```
Couldn't find Contact with ID=117 for Customer with ID=
```

Apparently what is happening is that when I pass the param to the `Customer#new` method Rails is performing a lookup on the CustomerContact table to try to get to the Contacts table so it can get the information for the Contact. However, since this is a new Customer, that association isn't setup yet since the Customer hasn't been created.

### Ok... So then I got this idea

What if I removed existing contacts from the `contact_attributes` and created the `customer_contacts` association directly!!! So that where the `myparams['customer_contacts_attributes'] = []` comes into play:

```
# convert the params to a Hash so we can manuipulate them
myparams = customer_params.to_h
# so we can create a record on the customer_contacts association
# directly if the contact already exits
myparams['customer_contacts_attributes'] = []    

# if we have contacts we want to assign to the customer
if myparams['contacts_attributes']
  # loop through each contact they entered
  myparams['contacts_attributes'].each do |k,v|
    # see if the contact exists in the database and isn't being destroyed
    if Contact.exists?(email: v['email']) && v['_destroy'] != '1'
      # grab the contact information
      contact = Contact.where(email: v['email']).first
      # just a double check that we got the contact from the database
      if contact
        # removed the contact
        myparams['contacts_attributes'].delete(k)
        # create the `customer_contact` association directly
        myparams['customer_contacts_attributes'].push({'user_id': contact.id})
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And... IT WORKED!!!! Well some what. The customer gets saved, contacts that already exists in the database get assigned and new contacts get created and assigned... so what's the issue then??? Well... if validation fails for any reason and the page gets redrawn, the existing contact the user entered is gone from the form.

### My plea for help

So I have this some what working but I really need help. I need to have it so that if validation fails the contact shows back up in the form. Also, obviously this isn't the best way to do this. I'm hoping someone has done something like this before in rails and has a better way of accomplishing it.

The my association setup is below:

```
class CustomerContact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :contact
end

class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :customer_contacts
  has_many :contacts, through: :customer_contacts

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer_contacts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts, allow_destroy: true
end

class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :customer_contacts
  has_many :customers, through: :customer_contacts
end
```

The contact section setup is below, note that I use this in both the new and edit actions:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Department</th>
    <th>Manager</th>
    <th>
      <%= link_to_add_association f, :contacts, class: 'btn btn-primary', partial: 'contact_fields', data: {
          association_insertion_node: '.contact_fields', association_insertion_method: :append
      } do %>
          <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
      <% end %>
    </th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="contact_fields">
  <%= f.fields_for :contacts do |contact| %>
      <%= render 'projects/contact_fields', f: contact %>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

the `contact_fields` partial is below:

```
<tr class="nested-fields">
  <td>
    <%= f.text_field :fullname, class: 'form-control invoke-contacts-search contact-fullname' %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control invoke-contacts-search contact-email' %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= f.text_field :phone, class: 'form-control contact-phone' %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= f.text_field :department, class: 'form-control contact-department' %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= f.text_field :manager, class: 'form-control contact-manager' %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= link_to_remove_association  f, class: 'btn btn-danger' do %>
        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
    <% end %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Here is the controller new and create action

```
def new
  @customer = Customer.new
  4.times { @customer.contacts.build }
end

def create

# convert the params to a Hash so we can manuipulate them
myparams = customer_params.to_h
# so we can create a record on the customer_contacts association
# directly if the contact already exits
myparams['customer_contacts_attributes'] = []    

# if we have contacts we want to assign to the customer
if myparams['contacts_attributes']
  # loop through each contact they entered
  myparams['contacts_attributes'].each do |k,v|
    # see if the contact exists in the database and isn't being destroyed
    if Contact.exists?(email: v['email']) && v['_destroy'] != '1'
      # grab the contact information
      contact = Contact.where(email: v['email']).first
      # just a double check that we got the contact from the database
      if contact
        # removed the contact
        myparams['contacts_attributes'].delete(k)
        # create the `customer_contact` association directly
        myparams['customer_contacts_attributes'].push({'user_id': contact.id})
      end
    end
  end
end

  @customer = Customers.new(myparams)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @customer.save
      format.html { redirect_to edit_customer_path(@customer), success: 'Customer was successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
    end
  end
end
```

Here are the controllers edit and and update action

```
def edit
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  myparams = customer_params.to_h

  if myparams['contacts_attributes']
    myparams['contacts_attributes'].each do |k,v|
      if Contacts.exists?(email: v['email']) && v['_destroy'] != '1'
        contact = Contact.where(email: v['email']).first
        if contact
          myparams['contacts_attributes'][k]['id'] = contact.id
          CustomerContact.find_or_create_by(project_id: @customer.id, user_id: contact.id)
        end
      end
    end
  end

  @customer.assign_attributes(myparams)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @customer.save
      format.html { redirect_to edit_customer_path(@customer), success: 'Customer was successfully updated.' }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure, but check the input fields on `.nested-fields`, you'll se that the name of the input is something like `customer[contacts_attributes][:somenumber][....]`, that number is a random big integer for new records and the ID for existing ones. I think you can manipulate that ID to chose an existing records (you could have an autocomplete feature on some of the fields, select one from a dropdown, fill the fields and change it's name with the contact id). Then rails won't create a new record with those values since the ID exists. Maybe you need an `f.hidden_field :id`, though.

Comment: That's what the manipulation of the params is doing in create and update actions. I will update my question to reflect this.

Comment: I meant you can do that on the frontend, add an autocomplete feature on the email field, when you start typing show the user some options and on click replace the fields and the ID of the element. That way you have a nice autocomplete to assign contacts and you don't need to manipulate params serverside.

Comment: I hear you and trust me... that's exactly what I wanted to do, however the client doesn't want that. Also that didn't solve the `Couldn't find Contact with ID=117 for Customer with ID=` issue I was having during the create. I appreciate your comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally got this to work, but I basically had to reimplment everything that nested attributes does for you in order to get this to work. It isn't pretty, but it works perfectly.

Also... Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55454504/can-you-the-coccon-gem-without-a-direct-nested-association/55464926#55464926) to see how I did the contact collection in the template

```
  def update

    myparams = customer_params.to_h
    contacts_valid = true
    @customer.assign_attributes(myparams)
    customer_valid = @customer.valid?
    @contacts = []
    contacts_to_delete = []

    cparams = contact_params.to_h
    cparams['contacts'].each do |k, v|
      if v['id'].to_i > 0
        if v['_destroy'].to_i == 1
          contacts_to_delete << v['id'].to_i
        else
          contact = Contact.find(v['id'])
          contact.assign_attributes(v.except('_destroy', 'id'))
        end
      else
        if (!v['name'].blank? || !v['email'].blank?) && v['_destroy'].to_i != 1
          unless v['email'].blank?
            contact = Contact.where(email: v['email']).first
          end
          if contact
            contact.assign_attributes(v.except('_destroy', 'id'))
          else
            contact = Contact.new(v.except('_destroy', 'id'))
          end
        end
      end

      if contact
        unless contact.valid?
          contacts_valid = false
          # This adds the errors from the contact to the customer object
          contact.errors.full_messages.each do |m|
            @customer.errors.add(:base, m)
          end
        end
        @contacts << contact
      end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if customer_valid && contacts_valid
        @customer.save!
        @contacts.each do |c|
          c.save!
          CustomerContact.find_or_create_by(customer_id: @customer.id, contact_id: c.id)
        end
        CustomerContact.where(customer_id: @customer.id, contact_id: contacts_to_delete).destroy_all

        format.html { redirect_to edit_customer_path(@customer), success: 'Customer was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @customer }
      else
        format.html {
          (6 - @contacts.count).times { @contacts << @customer.contacts.build }
          render :edit
        }
        format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end

  def customer_params
    params.require(:customer).permit(:company, :name, :line1, :line2, :city, :state, :zipcode, :country, :webaddress, :status,
                                     contacts_attributes: [:fullname, :phone, :email, :department, :manager, :id, :_destroy],
                                     notes_attributes: [:note]
    )
  end

  def contact_params
    params.permit(contacts: [:fullname, :email, :phone, :department, :manager, :id, :_destroy])
  end
```